# Is this the correct method to compute the directional derivative of $X_p[f]$?

Tags: differential-geometry

Say we have a smooth function

$f(x,y,z)=z^2+7x^2e^{yz}$

and a vector field

$X(x,y,z)=(-x,y,z)$

Now say we want to calculate the directional derivative $X(p)[f]$ at the point $p=(0,1,2)$. Then is this the correct method :

$X(p)[f]=\tfrac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}f(\alpha(t))$

$\alpha(t)=p+tX=(0,1,2)+t(-x,y,z)=(0,1,2)+t(0,1,2)=(0,1+t,2+2t)$

$\therefore f(\alpha(t))=(2+2t)^2=4+8t+4t^2$

$\tfrac{df(\alpha(t)}{dt}=8+8t$

so

$\tfrac{df(\alpha(t)}{dt}|_{t=0}=8$

which is just a scalar number.

Note: the reason I'm asking is because i'm studying for an exam an I wasn't sure whether $p+tx=(0,1,2)+t(-x,y,z)=(-tx,1+ty,2+2z)$ or whether it was what I stated above , above produces a scalar this method produces a smooth function.

Comment: You need *any* curve $\alpha(t)$ with $\alpha(0)=p$ and $\alpha'(0)=X(p)$. In your second try, I don't know what $x$, $y$, and $z$ are. Do you?

Comment: @TedShifrin In the second try I just meant x,y,z to represent the vector field , but I left it arbitrary in that case , In the first try I calculated X at the point p and then x,y,z became (0,1,2). So the first try is right then ?

Comment: Well, you could use the *flow* of the vector field $X$, in which case $\alpha(t)$ will not be a line but instead a curve with $\alpha'(t) = X(\alpha(t))$ instead.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry but I don't really follow you, Ive only had one course on introductory differential geometry , this method was just the one we saw in class so I think its safer to just stick with it as long as its correct

Comment: The definition of directional derivative you get in multivariable calculus is what you wrote down — you do the instantaneous rate of change (at the point) along a line through the point in the given direction.